# document.insertBefore throws error

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code:

```
  <textarea id="test" style="width: 400px; height: 100px"></textarea>
  <script>
    var inserting = document.createElement("div");
    document.insertBefore(inserting,document.getElementById("test"));
  </script>
```

Which should insert `DIV id=inserting` before `textarea id=test`, but this error occurs

```
Node was not found" code: "8
```

I use FireFox 3.6 with Firebug on WinXP. Where is the problem?

Comment: You can use [document.currentscript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) to do that job from firefox 4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`insertBefore` needs to called on the parent element of the element before which is inserted:

```
<textarea id="test" style="width: 400px; height: 100px"></textarea>
  <script>
    var inserting = document.createElement("div");
    var insertAt = document.getElementById("test");
    insertAt.parentNode.insertBefore(inserting,insertAt);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

`.insertBefore()` needs to be called on a DOM node. `document` is not a DOM node. Try using the parent node of your textarea.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you need to call `insertBefore` on the parent of the `<textarea>` node. According to the API documentation for [Node.insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore):

> **Summary**
>
> Inserts the specified node before a reference element as a child of the current node.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `var insertedElement = parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement);`
>
> If referenceElement is null, newElement is inserted at the end of the list of child nodes.
>
> - `insertedElement` The node being inserted, that is newElement
> - **`parentElement`** The parent of the newly inserted node.
> - `newElement` The node to insert.
> - `referenceElement` The node before which newElement is inserted.

So you want to say something along the lines of:

```
parent_element_goes_here.insertBefore(inserting,document.getElementById("test"));
```

Instead of:

```
document.insertBefore(inserting,document.getElementById("test"));
```

---

Also, your code may be executing before the DOM has finished being loaded. You can ensure all of the DOM elements are loaded by using the [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/window.onload) event handler. From the MDC docs:

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

So instead of calling your code directly, you would do this:

```
window.onload=function(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't work. delaying the script does nothing here because the dom is fine.

Comment: Thank you, the link you provided was very useful.

Answer (score -1):

You want to add your node to `document.body` not `document`:

```
document.body.insertBefore(inserting, document.getElementById("test"));
```

Comment: lol who is downvoting this 7 years later. it was correct then and it's still correct- the textarea belongs to `document.body`, not `document`.

Comment: It wasn't me, but the downvote is fair: if the textarea is not DIRECT child of body (i.e. nested in div), it is unspecified behavior and Opera gives me error `Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.` The question contains just a snippet, not the whole code.