# I wanted my image to insertBefore to the "li" but it just inserted after the ul closing tag

Tags: javascript

I wanted my image to insertBefore to the "li" but it just inserted after the ul closing tag

```
<ul id="inputId">
        <li><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />a.</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />b.</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />c.</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />d.</li>
</ul>
<script>
var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("id", "imgCheck");
    img.setAttribute("src", "image.jpg");

    var bar = document.querySelector("ul li");
    document.body.insertBefore(img, bar[0]);
</script>
```

Comment: `ul div li` is invalid nesting, for starters. Likely your problems stem from that.

Comment: And it says *node was not found* because `chooseList` is not a child of `<body>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.insertBefore throws error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043327/document-insertbefore-throws-error)

Comment: Validate your HTML https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: sorry about the invalid nesting. I already change the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fixed your HTML to be valid, but your JavaScript is still generating invalid HTML. You cannot nest `<ul><img><li>...`. The `<img>` must go inside the `<li>`. Try this (I used a test image to demonstrate):

```html
<ul id="inputId">
        <li><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />a.</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />b.</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />c.</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />d.</li>
</ul>
<script>
var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("id", "imgCheck");
    img.setAttribute("src", "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/080177fd3b72afcc226d30d73b258daa?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");

    var bar = document.querySelector("ul li");
    bar.insertBefore(img, bar.childNodes[0]);
</script>
```

If you instead want to replace the bullets of the list with an image, try this:

```html
<ul id="inputId">
        <li><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />a.</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />b.</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />c.</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />d.</li>
</ul>
<script>
    document.querySelector("ul").style.listStyleImage = "url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/080177fd3b72afcc226d30d73b258daa?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1')";
</script>
```